# How is Euler's Formula Wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers, pi

I figured out that if $x^{y} = z$, then $z^y = x^{y^2}$. Then we know Euler's Formula:

$$e^{πi} = -1,\quad
(e^π)^i = -1,\quad
(e^{2π})^i = 1$$

Now, using the formula above, let $e^{2π}$ act as x, and let i act as y. Then, finally, let 1 act as z. Accordingly, $z^{y}$, which is $1^i$, equals $x^{y^2}$, which is $(e^{2π})^{i^2}$. This means:

$$1^i = (e^{2π})^{-1}$$

Since $1^i = 1$:

$$1 = 1/(e^{2π})$$
$$(e^{2π}) = 1$$

But $(e^{2π}) ≠ 1$, so...(!!)

How is this possible?! And I think I actually figured this out!!!

Comment: The complex exponential is multivalued.

Comment: PLease see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @Sean The logarithm is multivalued. The exponential is certainly not.

Comment: @SeanRoberson the complex exponential is *not injective*

Comment: I believe Sean is talking about the general case of [complex exponents with complex bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases).

Answer (score 3):

Exponents only behave well under certain conditions. For instance, when the base is a positive real number and the exponent is real, or when the base is non-zero and the exponent is an integer.

The more you move away from such requirements, the more careful you have to be when applying rules like $a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$ and $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$. They will not always work.

Comment: What i disproved is a rule!

Comment: Other uses of i like this work:

Comment: (e^pi)^i = -1                 (-1)^i still equals (e^pi)^(-1) which is 1/(e^pi)                        In fact, I have looked for this for a long time and found it extremely hard to find this SPECIFIC case, which as far as I have seen disproves Euler’s Formula.

Comment: @MathBob What you have disproven isn't Euler's formula, you have disproven $(e^{2\pi i})^i=(e^{2\pi})^{i^2}$. In other words, you have shown exactly what I said in the answer: be careful when applying the usual exponent rules for more exotic exponent expressions, because they may not work.

Comment: How come these exponent rules work in every single case except these types of specific cases:

Comment: : (2^i)^i = 0.5        (4^i)^i = 0.25            (3^i)^i = 0.(3)        (5^i)^i = 0.2

Comment: Even (e^i)^i = 1/e    Just there is something special about that ^2pi  !

Comment: Wait a second:  So this formula applies when i is the exponent:                                     x^i = cos(ln(x)) + (sin(ln(x))*i)                                                                                               Google gives me the answer: 2^i = 0.769238901 + 0.638961276 i

Comment: ln(0.769238901 + 0.638961276 i) = -4.80382009 × 10-10 + 0.693147181 i

Comment: Ill continue later

Comment: @MathBob You haven't checked every single case, though. For instance, try $(e^{(2\pi +1)i})^i$. You do not get $1/e$. But $e^{(2\pi +1)i}$ is _exactly_ the same number as $e^i$, so you _should_ get $1/e$.

Comment: Yes, but cases including e and pi are the only ones discluded. Try to find a single one. A case with e and pi is discluded above. Then again, you see that if the equality e^(pi*i) = -1 did not exist, then

Comment: Well these complex exponets might behave